# ingresar N números enteros, me muestre el promedio de los números pares y la cantidad de los números pares

Tags: php

quiero decirles que tengo este problema: Generar un programa que me permita ingresar N números enteros, me muestre el promedio de los números pares y la cantidad de los números pares.

Es para mi hijo, si alguna vez programe lo hice en pascal y viendo el código que se usa en PHP, no logro hacer nada.

Sólo logro generar la lista de los números con:

```php
<?php
        $numero = 0;

        for ($i=0;$i<=9;$i++){
            $v[$i]=rand(1,100);
            echo $v[$i]. "<br/>";
        }

         for($i=0;$i<$numero; $i++ ){
         if ($numero%2==0)

         {
             $par = $numero + 2;

               echo "la suma es:" $par;

         }
         else{
             $impar = $numero+1;
         echo "la suma es:"$impar;
         }
        }
    ?>
```

y ahí me quedo, o sea, en la nada misma y lo necesita para el lunes.

Desde ya muy agradecido a quien me desee ayudar.

Saludos cordiales, Franco.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad StackOverflow. Es conveniente que muestres el código que no te funciona, para que partiendo de él podamos echarte un cable. Venga un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizaremos 3 `array`. Uno tendrá todos los números, otro tendrá números impares y el ultimo tendrá los números pares.

Mediante el modulo y la comparación del residuo con `0` sabremos si es par o no `%2==0`.

Una vez tengamos separados nuestros valores, utilizaremos la función creada `average()` para obtener el promedio.

```
<?php
$numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$pares = array();
$impares = array();

foreach($numbers as $number){
 if(is_par($number)){
    array_push($pares, $number);
 }else{
    array_push($impares, $number);
 }
}

if(empty($numbers)){
 die("No se pueden obtener datos desde un array vacio.");
}

echo "Promedio pares: " . average($pares) . 
     " Numeros: " . implode(",", $pares);

echo " Total impares: " . count($impares) . 
     " Numeros: " . implode(",", $impares);

function is_par($number){
 return $number % 2 == 0;
}

function average($values){
 $values = array_filter($values, function($x) { return $x !== ''; });
 $average = array_sum($values) / count($values);
 return $average;
}
```